# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED from socket.io

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I'm trying to run Node.js application. With SSH I am able to run 'node server.js':

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(5431);
app.use(express.static('public'));
console.log("### RUNNING ###");
var socket = require('socket.io');
var io = socket(server);
```

and it indeed logs and throws no errors. But when I open client-browser app, I get following output in console:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
GET http://localhost:5431/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MWCsv9T net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Client connects with:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5431');
```

I've tried connecting both with IP and domain, with same result. App worked fine on local machine.

I've checked open ports with following php script:

```
    for($i=0; $i<10000; $i++) {
    portCheck($i);
  }

  function portCheck($port) {
    if(stest('127.0.0.1', $port))
      echo $port . "<br>";
  }

  function stest($ip, $portt) {
    $fp = @fsockopen($ip, $portt, $errno, $errstr, 0.1);
    if (!$fp) {
        return false;
    } else {
        fclose($fp);
        return true;
    }
  }
```

and I did get:

[image]

As it listed 5431 I'm assuming that port is indeed open.

I have no idea then what can cause this error.

Answer (score 3):

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5431');
```

This means the client will connect to the **local** machine - where **local** is from the perspective of the system where script is executing. Since the script is executing in the browser it means that your application is expected to run on the clients machine where the browser is running.

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
GET http://localhost:5431/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MWCsv9T net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

While you don't explicitly say this a later statement (see below) suggests that this is done on a different machine than your application is running on. If your application is running on host A and your browser on host B then `localhost` inside the client browser (where script gets executed) refers to host B and not host A.

> App worked fine on local machine

This is expected since in this case `localhost` is the machine where your application is actually running on (same machine for application and browser).

Comment: "I've tried connecting both with IP and domain, with same result.' I don't run this line on web app, I replaced it with domain name as I said.

Comment: @TheRuthlessHacker: *"...tried connecting both with IP and domain"* - given the URL I've assumed that this meant that you've tried `127.0.0.1` and `localhost` and not that you've tried the external IP address or the public visible name. Especially since the error message you show clearly refers to the `localhost` URL. But if you are using the external IP/name make sure that port 5431 is actually reachable from outside with the given domain name or IP address, i.e. that these are valid and that no firewall is blocking the access.

Comment: I'm in WSL2 and this was indeed the cause of the browser not being able to connect to the socket through localhost. I just tested in WSL's Chrome browser and its working.